# react native , show a stacknavigator over a modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following react-navigation setup :

```
const MyTabView = TabNavigator(
  { ...
    NewObservation: { screen: NewObservation },
  },
  { ... }
);

const StackView = StackNavigator(
  {
    global: {
      screen: MyTabView,
      headerMode: "none",
      header: null,
      navigationOptions: {header: null}
    },
    ...
    SeeDetails: { screen: SeeDetails }
  },
  { mode: 'modal' }
);

<StackView/>
```

NewObservation simplified code

```
class NewObservation extends React.Component {
  ... 
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        animationType={"none"}
        transparent={false}
        visible={this.state.visibleModal}
        onRequestClose={() => this.setState({visibleModal:false}) }
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text>modal</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity underlayColor={Config.touchOpacityColor} style={styles.backButton}
            onPress={() =>
              this.props.navigation.navigate("SeeDetails", { ... })
            } >
            <Text>go to stack</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal >
    )
}
```

So i'm in "NewObservation tab", inside it i have a modal displayed.

**PROBLEME**

If i click on the "go to stack" , the stack view appair but under this modal, it show when i close the modal only.

How to make it appear over the modal on top always ?

Comment: set `this.state.visibleModel` to `False` so the Modal will be hided?

Comment: no because in the NewObservation  controller ajax query are made and i don't want to loose the content. i need to show the stackview ON TOP of the modal . and when click "back button" on the stackview to show the modal